# Notepad++: How to extract string between 2 slash?

Tags: regex, string, notepad++, slash

I can match string between 2 slash with this regex

> /.*/

However, I want to extract that string. So, how to do that ?
The string like this:

> youth   (n)    /ju:θ /  nguyên hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture group `( )` :

```
/(.*)/
```

And extract the required string with `\1`

Comment: Hi, It worked but it only remove slash. How to remove everything but string ?

Comment: If you are replacing..You can use `.*?/(.*?)/.*` to match and replace with `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

`/(.*)/`